# Angular http get request

Tags: angular

I am trying to send http get request on angular.

how do I add apikey on Authorization, I am able to that only on Postman since you just put values.

```
this.http
  .get(url)
  .pipe()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

when I send this request, it says unauthorized because api key missing

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to [add headers](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/#httpheaders) to a request using `HttpHeaders`:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
```

and you can pass them like this:

```
this.http.get(url, { headers }) // ...
```

Comment: I would go the Angular way and use interceptors: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
let header = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Authorization",
       localStorage.getItem("token")
    );

return this.http.get(url, {headers:header}).pipe()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first if the apiKey is return from the Backend when you execute the auth request
2. If yes you need to execute first the auth request in Angular (POST REQUEST): enter the login paramer and you will receive the token/apiKey.

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {} // in Component
(server: 'http://localhost:5000/api) // in environment.ts

```
***login(user: { username: string, password: string }): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.server}/auth`, user)
  .pipe(
    tap(tokens => this.doLoginUser(user.username, tokens)),
    mapTo(true),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error.error);
      return of(false);
    }));
```

}***

3. Use this Token to get specifical data from the db

   ***public getUserInfos() {
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.USER_INFOS));
   }***

I hope I could help